# Can't access querystring values by key name but can by index

Tags: asp.net, routes, query-string, handler

I have the following Url: `http://localhost:60815/Image.ashx?w=202&h=0&f=somefile`

I am getting an `Index was out of range. Must be non-negative and less than the size of the collection.` error when accessing one of the params via:

```
Int32.TryParse(context.Request.QueryString['w'], out width);
```

I can however access the values using the index, i.e:

```
Int32.TryParse(context.Request.QueryString[0], out width);
```

When I view the querystring (in debug immediate window), it does know about the keys:

```
context.Request.QueryString
{w=202&h=0&f=somefile}
   [System.Web.HttpValueCollection]: {w=202&h=0&f=somefile}
   base {System.Collections.Specialized.NameObjectCollectionBase}: {w=202&h=0&f=somefile}
   AllKeys: {string[3]} // [0]=w, [1]=h, [2]=f
```

Can someone explain why this is happening? It's not a problem accessing them by index but I would like to know why accessing via the key isn't working.

Note: My project is an MVC one and I haven't setup any specific routes to deal with handlers so I don't know if that could be causing an issue.

Comment: Did you try context.Request.QueryString["w"] with double quotes?

Comment: Oh, whoops. I have been doing PHP today so didn't even notice I was using single quotes. It's converting it into a char I assume so that's what's causing the issue *blush*

Comment: I'll post it as answer. It's working for you now?

Comment: Yes it is, thanks. I'll accept when I can. Thanks Irish.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using double quotes:

```
context.Request.QueryString["w"]
```

Comment: One of those moments you start to wonder why you are still programming at 10pm after start at 7am ... Time to watch a film :)

Comment: The guy looking over our shoulder always gets the answer off the bat ;-)